# Huge File Transfer Images from one FTP to Another - PHP

Tags: php, cron

I have an FTP "A" where in "images" folder there are almost 3,00,000 images.

I have an FTP "B" where in "images" folder there are almost 3,00,000 images.

Same images on both the servers.

I want to Write a Cron to check if there is any new image added to FTP "A" it should copy the same image to FTP "B"

I know its simple task to compare, but my problem is it takes almost 5 minutes to open the Folder on FTP using Filezilla... so what is the best method to transfer the new added images using PHP ?

Comment: Filezilla is not your php script, it gets the whole directory, your php could get just the newest by date. you need to at least make an attempt at this and post if\when you have a problem. php has built in ftp functions

Comment: rsync is the tool for the job.  it will even compare modified files not just new ones.

Comment: Don't use `cron` for this. Look at `incron` which will watch directories for certain file activities and start a process if they take place. No sense in synchronising when there's been no activity.

Comment: I suggest looking at directory comparison tools that are ftp based. A search using your favourite engine should prove useful.

Comment: Well a large part of your problem is having 3,000,000 files in a single folder. Pretty much any filesystem becomes a bag of excrement in situations like this simply because directory index lookups become a significant performance bottleneck. Organize your files better. Any folder with more than 1000 files in it is generally where performance starts to degrade noticeably. >1000, not good. >10000, bad. >100000, horrid.

Comment: @DavidChan rsync, yes. But it must not be an old version. I've run into a sufficiently ancient version that choked somewhere after 1 million files.

Comment: @Sammitch is correct about the contents of the bag... you should look into sharding the directory